UART communication on Basys 3 - Last bit not being read
I am implementing UART communication on Basys 3 to read / write data to a block RAM. A memory element I have is 48 bits (4, 12 bit numbers), but as UART communicates in bytes, I am using 6 bytes.
Issues:
In the first UART communication, the transmitter only shows 4 bits.
In the following transfers, the last byte of the previous transfer is given as the last byte of the current transfer.
I also connected a block ram to read a stream of bytes and store in the RAM from address 0 to the end, and then transmit the data from address 0 to the end. This gives rise to another set of errors. The starting byte and the final byte are the bytes that show inaccuracies
UART_TX
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;



entity UART_tx is

    generic(
        BAUD_CLK_TICKS: integer := 868); -- clk/baud_rate (100 000 000 / 115 200 = 868.0555)

    port(
        clk            : in  std_logic;
        reset          : in  std_logic;
        tx_start       : in  std_logic;
        tx_data_in     : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        tx_data_out    : out std_logic
        );
end UART_tx;


architecture Behavioral of UART_tx is

    type tx_states_t is (IDLE, START, DATA, STOP);
    signal tx_state  : tx_states_t := IDLE;


    signal baud_rate_clk     : std_logic:= '0';

    signal data_index        : integer range 0 to 7 := 0;
    signal data_index_reset  : std_logic := '1';
    signal stored_data       : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others=>'0');

    signal start_detected    : std_logic := '0';
    signal start_reset       : std_logic := '0';

begin


-- The baud_rate_clk_generator process generates the UART baud rate clock by
-- setting the baud_rate_clk signal when the counter counts BAUD_CLK_TICKS
-- ticks of the master clk. The BAUD_CLK_TICKS constant is specified in
-- the package and reflects the ratio between the master clk and the baud rate.

    baud_rate_clk_generator: process(clk)
    variable baud_count: integer range 0 to (BAUD_CLK_TICKS - 1) := (BAUD_CLK_TICKS - 1);
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (reset = '1') then
                baud_rate_clk <= '0';
                baud_count := (BAUD_CLK_TICKS - 1);
            else
                if (baud_count = 0) then
                    baud_rate_clk <= '1';
                    baud_count := (BAUD_CLK_TICKS - 1);
                else
                    baud_rate_clk <= '0';
                    baud_count := baud_count - 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process baud_rate_clk_generator;


-- The tx_start_detector process works on the master clk frequency and catches
-- short (one clk cycle long) impulses in the tx_start signal and keeps it for
-- the UART_tx_FSM. tx_start_detector is needed because the UART_tx_FSM works on
-- the baud rate frequency, but the button_debounce module generates one master clk
-- cycle long impulse per one button push. start_detected keeps the information that
-- such event has occurred.
-- The second purpose of tx_start_detector is to secure the transmitting data.
-- stored_data keeps the transmitting data saved during the transmission.

    tx_start_detector: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (reset ='1') or (start_reset = '1') then
                start_detected <= '0';
            else
                if (tx_start = '1') and (start_detected = '0') then
                    start_detected <= '1';
                    stored_data <= tx_data_in;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process tx_start_detector;


-- The data_index_counter process is a simple counter from 0 to 7 working on the baud
-- rate frequency. It is used to perform transformation between the parallel
-- data (stored_data) and the serial output (tx_data_out).
-- The data_index signal is used in UART_tx_FSM to go over the stored_data vector
-- and send the bits one by one.

    data_index_counter: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (reset = '1') or (data_index_reset = '1') then
                data_index <= 0;
            elsif (baud_rate_clk = '1') then
                data_index <= data_index + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process data_index_counter;


-- The UART_FSM_tx process represents a Finite State Machine which has
-- four states (IDLE, START, DATA, STOP). See inline comments for more details.

    UART_tx_FSM: process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (reset = '1') then
                tx_state <= IDLE;
                data_index_reset <= '1';   -- keep data_index_counter on hold
                start_reset <= '1';        -- keep tx_start_detector on hold
                tx_data_out <= '1';        -- keep tx line set along the standard
            else
                if (baud_rate_clk = '1') then   -- the FSM works on the baud rate frequency
                    case tx_state is

                        when IDLE =>

                            data_index_reset <= '1';    -- keep data_index_counter on hold
                            start_reset <= '0';         -- enable tx_start_detector to wait for starting impulses
                            tx_data_out <= '1';         -- keep tx line set along the standard

                            if (start_detected = '1') then
                                tx_state <= START;
                            end if;

                        when START =>

                            data_index_reset <= '0';   -- enable data_index_counter for DATA state
                            tx_data_out <= '0';        -- send '0' as a start bit

                            tx_state <= DATA;

                        when DATA =>

                            tx_data_out <= stored_data(data_index);   -- send one bit per one baud clock cycle 8 times

                            if (data_index = 7) then
                                data_index_reset <= '1';              -- disable data_index_counter when it has reached 8
                                tx_state <= STOP;
                            end if;

                        when STOP =>

                            tx_data_out <= '1';     -- send '1' as a stop bit
                            start_reset <= '1';     -- prepare tx_start_detector to be ready detecting the next impuls in IDLE

                            tx_state <= IDLE;

                        when others =>
                            tx_state <= IDLE;
                    end case;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process UART_tx_FSM;


end Behavioral;

UART_RX
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;



entity UART_rx is

    generic(
        BAUD_X16_CLK_TICKS: integer := 54); -- (clk / baud_rate) / 16 => (100 000 000 / 115 200) / 16 = 54.25

    port(
        clk            : in  std_logic;
        reset          : in  std_logic;
        rx_data_in     : in  std_logic;
        rx_valid       : out std_logic;
        rx_data_out    : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
        );
end UART_rx;


architecture Behavioral of UART_rx is

    type rx_states_t is (IDLE, START, DATA, STOP);
    signal rx_state: rx_states_t := IDLE;

    signal baud_rate_x16_clk  : std_logic := '0';
    signal rx_stored_data     : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');



begin


-- The baud_rate_x16_clk_generator process generates an oversampled clock.
-- The baud_rate_x16_clk signal is 16 times faster than the baud rate clock.
-- Oversampling is needed to put the capture point at the middle of duration of
-- the receiving bit.
-- The BAUD_X16_CLK_TICKS constant reflects the ratio between the master clk
-- and the x16 baud rate.

    baud_rate_x16_clk_generator: process(clk)
    variable baud_x16_count: integer range 0 to (BAUD_X16_CLK_TICKS - 1) := (BAUD_X16_CLK_TICKS - 1);
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (reset = '1') then
                baud_rate_x16_clk <= '0';
                baud_x16_count := (BAUD_X16_CLK_TICKS - 1);
            else
                if (baud_x16_count = 0) then
                    baud_rate_x16_clk <= '1';
                    baud_x16_count := (BAUD_X16_CLK_TICKS - 1);
                else
                    baud_rate_x16_clk <= '0';
                    baud_x16_count := baud_x16_count - 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process baud_rate_x16_clk_generator;


-- The UART_rx_FSM process represents a Finite State Machine which has
-- four states (IDLE, START, DATA, STOP). See inline comments for more details.

    UART_rx_FSM: process(clk)
        variable bit_duration_count : integer range 0 to 15 := 0;
        variable bit_count          : integer range 0 to 7  := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if (reset = '1') then
                rx_state <= IDLE;
                rx_valid <= '0';
                rx_stored_data <= (others => '0');
                rx_data_out <= (others => '0');
                bit_duration_count := 0;
                bit_count := 0;
            else
                if (baud_rate_x16_clk = '1') then     -- the FSM works 16 times faster the baud rate frequency
                    case rx_state is

                        when IDLE =>
                            rx_valid <= '0';
                            rx_stored_data <= (others => '0');    -- clean the received data register
                            bit_duration_count := 0;              -- reset counters
                            bit_count := 0;

                            if (rx_data_in = '0') then             -- if the start bit received
                                rx_state <= START;                 -- transit to the START state
                            end if;

                        when START =>

                            if (rx_data_in = '0') then             -- verify that the start bit is preset
                                if (bit_duration_count = 7) then   -- wait a half of the baud rate cycle
                                    rx_state <= DATA;              -- (it puts the capture point at the middle of duration of the receiving bit)
                                    bit_duration_count := 0;
                                else
                                    bit_duration_count := bit_duration_count + 1;
                                end if;
                            else
                                rx_state <= IDLE;                  -- the start bit is not preset (false alarm)
                            end if;

                        when DATA =>
                            if (bit_duration_count = 15) then                -- wait for "one" baud rate cycle (not strictly one, about one)
                                rx_stored_data(bit_count) <= rx_data_in;     -- fill in the receiving register one received bit.
                                bit_duration_count := 0;
                                if (bit_count = 7) then                      -- when all 8 bit received, go to the STOP state
                                    rx_state <= STOP;
                                    bit_duration_count := 0;
                                else
                                    bit_count := bit_count + 1;
                                end if;
                            else
                                bit_duration_count := bit_duration_count + 1;
                            end if;

                        when STOP =>
                            if (bit_duration_count = 15) then      -- wait for "one" baud rate cycle
                                rx_valid <= '1';
                                rx_data_out <= rx_stored_data;     -- transer the received data to the outside world
                                rx_state <= IDLE;
                            else
                                bit_duration_count := bit_duration_count + 1;
                            end if;

                        when others =>
                            rx_state <= IDLE;
                    end case;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process UART_rx_FSM;

end Behavioral;

UART
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;



entity UART is

    port(
        clk            : in  std_logic;
        reset          : in  std_logic;
        tx_start       : in  std_logic;
        rx_valid       : out std_logic;

        tx_data_in        : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        rx_data_out       : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

        rx             : in  std_logic;
        tx             : out std_logic
        );
end UART;


architecture Behavioral of UART is

    component UART_tx
        port(
            clk            : in  std_logic;
            reset          : in  std_logic;
            tx_start       : in  std_logic;
            tx_data_in     : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
            tx_data_out    : out std_logic
            );
    end component;


    component UART_rx
        port(
            clk            : in  std_logic;
            reset          : in  std_logic;
            rx_data_in     : in  std_logic;
            rx_valid       : out std_logic;
            rx_data_out    : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
            );
    end component;

begin

    transmitter: UART_tx
    port map(
            clk            => clk,
            reset          => reset,
            tx_start       => tx_start,
            tx_data_in     => tx_data_in,
            tx_data_out    => tx
            );


    receiver: UART_rx
    port map(
            clk            => clk,
            reset          => reset,
            rx_data_in     => rx,
            rx_valid       => rx_valid,
            rx_data_out    => rx_data_out
            );


end Behavioral;

DUAL_PORT_RAM
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity DUAL_PORT_RAM is
    generic (
        ADDR_DEPTH : integer := 6;
        DATA_SIZE : integer := 48
    );
    port (
        clk       : in std_logic;
        en1       : in std_logic;
        en2       : in std_logic;
        addr1     : in integer range 0 to ADDR_DEPTH;
        addr2     : in integer range 0 to ADDR_DEPTH;
        write_en  : in std_logic;
        data_in   : in std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0);
        data_out : out std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0)
    );
end DUAL_PORT_RAM;

architecture behavioral of DUAL_PORT_RAM is
    type ram_type is array (0 to ADDR_DEPTH-1) of std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0);
    shared variable RAM : ram_type;
begin
    process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if en1 = '1' then
                if write_en = '1' then
                    RAM(addr1) := data_in;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;    
    end process;

    process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if en2 = '1' then
                data_out <= RAM(addr2);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end behavioral;


UART_CONTROLLER
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity CONTROLLER is
    generic(
        BUFFER_SIZE : integer := 6;
        ADDR_DEPTH : integer := 2;
        DATA_SIZE : integer := 48;
        BAUD_DELAY : integer := 13020
    );

    port(
        clk              : in  std_logic;
        reset            : in  std_logic;
        tx_enable        : in  std_logic;
        rx               : in  std_logic;
        tx               : out std_logic
        );
end CONTROLLER;


architecture Behavioral of CONTROLLER is

    component button_debounce
        port(
            clk        : in  std_logic;
            reset      : in  std_logic;
            button_in  : in  std_logic;
            button_out : out std_logic
            );
    end component;


    component UART
        port(
            clk            : in  std_logic;
            reset          : in  std_logic;
            tx_start       : in  std_logic;
            rx_valid       : out std_logic;

            tx_data_in        : in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
            rx_data_out       : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

            rx             : in  std_logic;
            tx             : out std_logic
            );
    end component;

    component DUAL_PORT_RAM is
        generic (
            ADDR_DEPTH : integer := 6;
            DATA_SIZE : integer := 48
        );
        port (
            clk       : in std_logic;
            en1       : in std_logic;
            en2       : in std_logic;
            addr1     : in integer range 0 to ADDR_DEPTH;
            addr2     : in integer range 0 to ADDR_DEPTH;
            write_en  : in std_logic;
            data_in   : in std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0);
            data_out : out std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0)
        );
    end component DUAL_PORT_RAM;

    signal button_pressed, tx_start, rx_valid : std_logic;
    signal new_data : std_logic := '0';
    signal rx_data_out, tx_data_in : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

    -- Internal signals using std_logic_vector
    signal data_buffer, result_buffer : std_logic_vector(8*BUFFER_SIZE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal rx_count : integer range 0 to BUFFER_SIZE := 0;
    signal tx_count : integer range 0 to BUFFER_SIZE := 0;
    signal addr1, addr2 : integer range 0 to ADDR_DEPTH := 0;

    type state_type is (IDLE, RECEIVING, WAITING, TRANSMITTING);
    signal current_state : state_type := RECEIVING;
    
    signal delay_counter : integer range 0 to BAUD_DELAY := 0;
    signal transmit_active : boolean := false;

    -- Internal signals to connect RAM
    signal ram_data_in, ram_data_out : std_logic_vector(DATA_SIZE-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal write_en : std_logic := '1';
    signal ram_port1_en, ram_port2_en : std_logic := '1';

begin
    ram : DUAL_PORT_RAM
    generic map(
        ADDR_DEPTH => ADDR_DEPTH,
        DATA_SIZE => DATA_SIZE
        )
    port map(
        clk => clk,
        en1 => ram_port1_en,
        en2 => ram_port2_en,
        write_en => write_en,
        addr1 => addr1,
        addr2 => addr2,
        data_in => ram_data_in,
        data_out => ram_data_out
        );

    tx_button_controller: button_debounce
    port map(
            clk            => clk,
            reset          => reset,
            button_in      => tx_enable,
            button_out     => button_pressed
            );

    UART_transceiver: UART
    port map(
            clk            => clk,
            reset          => reset,
            tx_start       => tx_start,
            rx_valid       => rx_valid,
            tx_data_in     => tx_data_in,
            rx_data_out    => rx_data_out,
            rx             => rx,
            tx             => tx
            );

    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset = '1' then
                rx_count <= 0;
                tx_count <= 0;
                addr1 <= 0;
                addr2 <= 0;
                delay_counter <= 0;

                new_data <= '1';
                tx_start <= '0';

                current_state <= IDLE;
                transmit_active <= false;
                
                data_buffer <= (others => '0');
                new_data <= '0';
                ram_data_in <= (others => '0');
                result_buffer <= (others => '0');
            else
                case current_state is
                    when IDLE => 
                        tx_start <= '0';
                        if rx_valid = '1' and new_data='1' then
                            current_state <= RECEIVING;
                        elsif rx_valid = '0' then
                            new_data <= '1';
                        end if;
                    when RECEIVING =>
                        tx_start <= '0';
                        
                        -- Store received byte in appropriate position within data_buffer
                        data_buffer(8*(rx_count+1)-1 downto 8*rx_count) <= rx_data_out;

                        if rx_count = BUFFER_SIZE-1 then
                            rx_count <= 0;                            
                            addr1 <= addr1;
                            ram_data_in <= data_buffer(8*BUFFER_SIZE-1 downto 0);    -- read the value

                            if addr1 = ADDR_DEPTH - 1 then
                                current_state <= WAITING;
                                addr1 <= 0;
                            else
                                current_state <= IDLE;
                                addr1 <= addr1 + 1;
                            end if;
                        else
                            rx_count <= rx_count + 1;
                            new_data <= '0';
                            current_state <= IDLE;
                        end if;
                        
                    when WAITING =>
                        if button_pressed='1' then
                            tx_count <= 0;
                            result_buffer <= ram_data_out;
                            current_state <= TRANSMITTING;
                            delay_counter <= 0;
                            transmit_active <= false;
                        end if;
                        
                    when TRANSMITTING =>
                        if not transmit_active then
                            -- Extract appropriate byte from 
                            tx_data_in <= result_buffer(8*(tx_count+1)-1 downto 8*tx_count);
                            tx_start <= '1';
                            transmit_active <= true;
                            delay_counter <= 0;
                        else
                            tx_start <= '0';
                            if delay_counter = BAUD_DELAY then
                                if tx_count = BUFFER_SIZE-1 then
                                    if addr2 = ADDR_DEPTH-1 then
                                        current_state <= IDLE;
                                        addr2 <= 0;
                                    else
                                        current_state <= WAITING;
                                        addr2 <= addr2 + 1;
                                    end if;
                                    tx_count <= 0;
                                else
                                    tx_count <= tx_count + 1;
                                end if;
                                transmit_active <= false;
                            else
                                delay_counter <= delay_counter + 1;
                            end if;
                        end if;
                end case;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
end Behavioral;

I can't seem to find the issue with the implementation. It would be a great help if I can get some assistance for this.
As its the issue with the last byte, I used a 1 byte padding and considered the rest of the bytes.
When writing a set of 5 bytes to the RAM using UART implemented above, (ADDR_DEPTH=5) I get the following output
Sent utf8 encoded message: "111111222222333333444444555555"
Sent utf8 encoded message: "0"
555555111111222222333333444444
The last 6 bytes are read as first. I am a bit confused where the error is.

See [ask] and [mcve]. Consider simulation as a means of debugging, requiring a testbench. Your dual_port_ram doesn't use any declarations from Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned. Your model appears to be small enough to use signals instead of pre -2002 shared variables allowing dual_port_ram contents to be monitored during simulation. The debounce entity and architecture are not present. The casual reader might expect a design issue with the controller state machine in the unlabelled process.

First of all, you should stop thinking in terms of encodings or any protocols over the media, i.e. your UART should send and receive bit stream / byte stream. So, try to operate on hex dumps and not on UTF-8 or anything like that. Second, check the implementation from opencore, perhaps it helps.
